# Hadoop and JDK compatibility

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

Does Hadoop Component like spark, hive , kafka support HP-UX operating systems because HP-UX o.s. has their own JDK , so question here is can I run Hadoop or spark on other than Oracle JDK , please reply.

Comment: To begin with, Spark and Kafka are **not** Hadoop components!!! Then it depends on whether you have Kerberos authentication enabled -- the JAAS implementations are different on Sun/Oracle and IBM, for instance (OpenJDK is a clone of Sun/Oracle, I don't know about he HP stuff).

Answer (score 0):

It may work I am not sure of the issues, Give it a try. 
Else
Install Oracle JDK and set the JAVA_HOME variable. Hadoop picks the installed version as the default.